# Use animation when changing activity

Tags: android, animation

I would like to use a right-to-left sliding animation when transitioning between two activities. So far, I have set up a command to pass to the next activity.

```
public void advancenext (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
        Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, I am having trouble incorporating the animation into this code. This is what I have so far for the `translation` animation

```
Animation set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(100);
  set.addAnimation(animation);

  animation = new TranslateAnimation(
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
  );
  animation.setDuration(500);
  set.addAnimation(animation);

  LayoutAnimationController controller =
      new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
```

How would I go about combining the animation information with the activity change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up an activity entrance animation, you must create a [tween animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween) (involving alpha, scale, translate, &c) in the `res\anim` folder and then call [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) just after invoking `startActivity()`.

For example, you could get an "activity enters from right and pushes the previous one out" effect (which if I understood correctly is what you need) with these animation files:

**push_left_exit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**push_left_enter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

It's advisable to set up a "reverse" animation when finishing the activity, so effect when the back button is pressed is coherent with the entrance.

Comment: Should these two commands be in separate xml files? or the same xml file

Comment: @user3616949 Separate, to use as the two parameters of overridePendingTransition(). Edited answer to make clearer.

Comment: Cool, one more question: do you know how I would modify my first command (the one switching activities) to incorporate this animation?

Comment: @user3616949 I quote: "Call overridePendingTransition() just after invoking startActivity()" :)

Comment: Awesome, last issue (sorry), both `startActivity()` and `overridePendingTransition()` get the errors `The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (int)` and `The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (int)`. Would you happen to know how to resolve this?

Comment: @user3616949 `overridePendingTransition()` has two parameters (which should be `R.anim.push_left_enter, R.anim.push_left_exit`. Looks like you're passing only one

Comment: how about startActivity()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54247/discussion-between-matiash-and-user3616949).